# Xamarin app that supports two displays

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Hello I am currently developing xamarin.form App. One of its features is to support devices that have two displays connected. I need one content page with my app on screen one and one with summary data shown. I did a bit of research  to get me going but nothing came up. So have somone have any ideas of the topic. If not i will post a sample app when I am done.

Comment: Do you mean split screen where you can run 2 apps in the same display? 
Do you mean old school flip-phones where they had a small screen on the back?

Comment: 2 screens 2 displays

Comment: Can you share a mobile device that has this technology? I didn't find anything about that in the news

Comment: The solutions I am writing it's for industrial PC. But must be supported as well for Android IOS devices. That's why I chose Xamarin. The devices are basicly small touch PC with big screens i am yet to see the android and IOS ones.

Comment: Here is a sample of a device.https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Android-dual-screen-pos-system_60748473150.html?spm=a2700.7735675.2017115.89.388nMi&s=p

Comment: This is a POS not a phone. It must have its own API to show the content in each screen if programmable. Xamarin is suppose to have access to the native API so it should support this type of devices but you may need a custom renderer to access the API of the POS system

Comment: The API for each of those devices may differ than others depending on the manufacturer. If it's the case, it doesn't make much sense to use Xamarin forms since Apple devices will not be supported and even android devices will need different custom renderer for each manufacture. Xamarin.Android or native Android might make more sense

Answer (score 1):

Android API level 26 supports multi-display by launching an Activity on a specific screen. See [`setLaunchDisplayId`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityOptions.html#setLaunchDisplayId(int)).

This is most likely not supported out of the box with Xamarin.Forms, as far as I know it is a single Activity App you create there.

iOS similarly has the concept of Windows, where a window shows a ViewController.

The easiest for you would probably be to avoid using Xamarin.Forms and use the native capabilities. Otherwise you'd have to wait for Xamarin.Forms to support such feature.

Comment: Thanks  that looks to be the case but I will keep digging